# Understanding LATERAL in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, lateral-join, lateral

Would like to know what is LATERAL and why LATERAL in SQL? Have few question to understand more on LATERAL. I searched in google and not getting clear understanding of LATERAL.

1. Why Lateral
2. Advantage of Lateral
3. Lateral View Vs Lateral Join.
4. What scenario we need to use Lateral View and Lateral join.

Please share your thought on this.

Comment: That is what the docs are for. Go here [Select](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html) and search on LATERAL.

Comment: The term lateral-join is wrong. It's not the join which is lateral, it's the subquery after the LATERAL keyword.